# nunit with -test takes a loooong time to start - without works fine

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I am using NUnit Console Runner 3.7.0 and similar nunit framework

Whenever I am running the console without specifying which tests to run, it runs at once.

As soon as I give it a few tests to runs it takes about 5 minutes to even start running.
I've tried running it against my testing dll and again against an .nunit project - same thing.

The assembly has about 130 tests but their discovery takes couple of seconds when using nunit -explore or visual studio test runner so it shouldn't be taking minutes to run them.

Example from my CI:

```
00:00:55.417      [exec] Test Filters
00:00:55.417      [exec]     Test: T1
00:00:55.418      [exec]     Test: T2
00:00:55.418      [exec]     Test: T3
00:00:55.419      [exec]     Test: T4
00:00:55.419      [exec]     Test: T5
00:00:55.419      [exec]     Test: T6
00:00:55.419      [exec] 
00:06:29.678      [exec] => T1
00:06:29.685      [exec]  
00:06:29.685      [exec] *******************************************************************************
00:06:29.685      [exec] *******************************************************************************
00:06:29.685      [exec] *******************************************************************************
00:06:29.685      [exec]                                    S T A R T
00:06:29.685      [exec]
```

Edit:
NUnit call(using nant):

```
<exec 
    program="nunit3-console.exe" 
    basedir="${nUnit.path}" 
    workingdir="${source.path}" 
    timeout="14400000"
    verbose="true">

    <arg value="${source.path}\Sources\Test.nunit" />
    <arg line ="--x86" />
    <arg line ="--labels=All" />
    <arg line ="--result=TestResult.xml" />
    <arg line ="-test=T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6" />
</exec>
```

When doing it manually:

```
nunit3-console.exe Test.dll --x86 -test=T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6
```

Comment: Can you provide the command-line you use to run selected tests?

Comment: Done - thanks for reminding me Charlie

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that this might be a bug in nunit 3*.

I've reverted to nunit 2.6.4 and it has no such problem.